# Largest prime factor - euler project

Tags: java

I was trying to solve project Euler [problem 3](http://projecteuler.net/problem=3) which is:

***The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?***

Here is my solution , it works for smaller values but somehow doesn't complete for the required number:

```
public class Pro3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long l=600851475143L;
        for(long lo=l/2;lo>=2;lo--){
            if(l%lo==0 && isPrime(lo)==true){
                    System.out.println(lo);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean isPrime(long x){
        for(int i=2;i<=Math.sqrt(x);i++){
            if(x%i==0){
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly happens?

Comment: My program just keeps on running , without any output or error.

Comment: It will eventually finish, in a really long time. Something like a thousand years. So in that respect, your program is not broken, just inefficient.

Comment: In addition, consider optimizing your isPrime code to increase efficiency. Building a list of known primes, and not dealing with even numbers other than 2, will significantly increase the speed of subsequent isPrime calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
 public static List<Double> primeFactors(double numbers) {
    double n  = numbers;
    List<Double> factors = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 2; i <= n / i; i++) {
        while (n % i == 0) {
            factors.add((double) i);
            n /= i;
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) {
        factors.add(n);
    }
    return factors;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   List<Double> result=primeFactors(600851475143d);
   System.out.println("largest prime factor is :" + result.get(result.size()-1));
}
```

Output:

```
largest prime factor is :6857.0
```

Comment: Is it really necessary to find the prime factors twice - the second time just to get the size? Also your program has a bug - primeFactors(16) would only return 2 once, instead of four times, and it would also take longer than necessary.

Comment: This works. Thanks. Can you provide a link which explains the algorithm of this ? Or it has a name ?

Answer (score 0):

Set the starting value for `lo` to `Math.sqrt(l) + 1`, change it to type `int` and it should work fine seeing as it is exactly what I did. The best guess I can come up with what is bugging in your code is the usage of 32-bit ALUs and integer overflow.

```
package page1;

import euler.Common;

/**
 * @author Obicere
 */
public class Euler003 {

    public static void main(final String[] args){
        long number = 600851475143L;
        int maxRange = (int) Math.sqrt(number) + 1;
        for(int i = maxRange; i >= 2; i--){
            if(number % i == 0 && Common.isPrime(i)){
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public static boolean isPrime(final int num) {
    if (num < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    if (num == 2) {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i <= (int) Math.sqrt(num) + 1; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```