# Issue trying project euler #3

Tags: java, logic

I'm trying to solve project euler number three, but I'm pretty messed up with the logic to stop the calculation.

Here is the Project Euler number three:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>
> What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

Well, I created a function to check if the number is prime:

```
public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if (number % 2 == 0)
        return false;
    
    for (int i = 3; i*i <= number; i+=2) {
        System.out.println("Dividing the number " + number + " by: " + i);
        if (number % i == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And a function to check if the prime number is a factor of the number:

```
 public static boolean isFactor(int number, int prime) {
    if (number % prime == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Only problem is the main function, I'm trying something like that:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int number = 13195;
    int i = 3;
    
    do {
        i++;
    } while (isPrime(i) && isFactor(number, i) == false);
    
    System.out.println(i);
    
}
```

I know the logic is not correct, but I'm really stuck on it for more than an hour.

I know the main goal here is to loop, find a prime and check if this prime is a factor of the number and find the biggest one, but the stopping condition would be if the looping number is a prime and is not a factor of the number.

Sorry for the mess, I'm pretty stuck :) thanks!

Comment: work for `number=63` you will get highest factor as `4` but highest factor is `7`. check your conditions for exiting from `do while loop`.

Comment: [here's your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772139/largest-prime-factor-euler-project?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your logic is you are starting with the smallest prime, and as soon as it hits a number which is prime and a factor of given number your program stops.
What you should do is start from other end. As we know any prime divisor of a number won't be greater than square root of the number, so you can do is:

```
int number = 13195;
int i = (int)Math.sqrt(number);

do {
    i--;
} while (isPrime(i) && isFactor(number, i) == false);

System.out.println(i);
```

There are other changes for 600851475143, this won't fit in int so try to use long where ever the you are doing calculation on it.

Here is my solution for this question, it is not 100% right but it works for this question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long number= 600851475143L;
    int rootOfNumber = (int)Math.sqrt(number)+10;
    for(int i = rootOfNumber; i > 2; i--) {
        if(number % i == 0) {
            if(psudoprime(i)) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

public static boolean psudoprime(int num) {
    for(int i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
        if(num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LargestPrimeFactor {
private long num;
public LargestPrimeFactor(long num){
    this.num=num;
}
public long calculate(){
    for(long i=1;i<=num/2;i++)
        if(num%i==0)
            if(isPrime(num/i)) 
                return num/i;

    return 1;
}
private static boolean isPrime(long num){
    for(long i=2;i<=(long)Math.sqrt(num);i++){
        if(num%i==0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The loop in the main code stops after finding the first prime divisor of the said number. We have to, instead, eliminate all such prime divisors until we reach the largest among them.
I am reluctant to share any code here because the question is really specific. Instead of breaking the loop at occurrence of a prime divisor try listing all of them.

Hope this helps.